# Pass variable in document.getElementByid in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable account_number in which account number is stored. now i want to get the value of the element having id as account_number. How to do it in javascript ?

I tried doing document.getElementById(account_number).value, but it is null.

html looks like this :

```
<input class='transparent' disabled type='text' name='113114234567_name' id='113114234567_name' value = 'Neeloy' style='border:0px;height:25px;font-size:16px;line-height:25px;' />
```

and the js is :

```
function getElement()
{   
 var acc_list = document.forms.editBeneficiary.elements.bene_account_number_edit;

    for(var i=0;i<acc_list.length;i++)
        {
            if(acc_list[i].checked == true)
                {

                    var account_number = acc_list[i].value.toString();
                    var ben_name = account_number + "_name";

                    alert(document.getElementById("'" + ben_name.toString() + "'").value);
                }
         }
```

}

here bene_account_number_edit are the radio buttons.

Thanks

Comment: Is the element w/ id account_number an <input> element or something else?

Comment: yes there is a input type in a form with id as account_number's value

Comment: <input class='transparent' disabled type='text' name='113114234567_name' id='113114234567_name' value = 'Neeloy' style='border:0px;height:25px;font-size:16px;line-height:25px;' />

Comment: id values cannot start with a number.  They must start with a letter.  They can have numbers in them so `name_113114234567` is a valid ID, but `113114234567_name` is not.

Comment: your taking the value and use it for the elementsId - this wont match ..

Comment: @jfriend00, `[id]` values *shouldn't* start with a number, but browsers are supposed to handle them correctly even if they do. `[id]` values *shouldn't* be repeated either, but if you have two elements with the same `[id]` the browser will select the first one when using `document.getElementById`

Comment: @zzzzBov - If you want to use illegal id values or duplicate id values, good luck getting the same behavior in different browsers.  Heck it's difficult enough to get the same behavior in all browsers WHEN you use legal HTML.  Why not follow the rules and make your life easier?

Comment: @jfriend00, i'm not saying that it's a good idea, i'm saying that that's not the cause of the problem.

Comment: @zzzzBov - that's why I wrote this as a comment, not an answer.  It's one thing to fix, but not necessarily the whole issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you storing just an integer as the element's `id` attribute? If so, browsers tend to behave in strange ways when looking for an element by an integer id. Try passing `account_number.toString()`, instead.

If that doesn't work, prepend something like "account_" to the beginning of your elements' `id` attributes and then call `document.getElementById('account_' + account_number).value`.

Comment: it's not working even after adding 'account_' and .toString() :-(

Comment: And you prepended `account_` to the `id` attribute of your `<input>` element? And the input's value is set beforehand?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you prefixing and post-fixing `'` characters to the name string? `ben_name` is already a string because you've appended `'_name'` to the value.

I'd recommend doing a `console.log` of `ben_name` just to be sure you're getting the value you expect.

the way to use a variable for `document.getElementById` is the same as for any other function:

```
document.getElementById(ben_name);
```

I don't know why you think it would act any differently.

Answer (score 0):

There is no use of converting ben_name to string because it is already the string.
Concatenation of two string will always give you string.

```
var account_number = acc_list[i].value.toString();
var ben_name = account_number + "_name";
```

try following code it will work fine

```
var ben_name=acc_list[i]+ "_name";
```

here also

```
alert(document.getElementById("'" + ben_name.toString() + "'").value);
```

try

```
alert(document.getElementById(ben_name).value);
```

I have tested similar type of code which worked correctly. If you are passing variable don't use quotes. What you are doing is passing ben_name.toString() as the value, it will definitely cause an error because it can not find any element with that id viz.(ben_name.toString()). In each function call, you are passing same value i.e. ben_name.toString() which is of course wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found this page in search for a fix for *my* issue...

Let's say you have a list of products:

```
<div class="rel-prod-item">
    <img src="assets/product-photos/title-of-the-related-product_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Western Digital 1TB" />
    <p class="rel-prod-title">Western Digital 1TB</p>
    <p class="rel-prod-price" id="price_format_1">149.95</p>
    <a href="#" title="Western Digital 1TB" class="gray-btn-sm add-to-cart text-shadow">add to cart</a>
</div>

<div class="rel-prod-item">
    <img src="assets/product-photos/title-of-the-related-product_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Western Digital 1TB" />
    <p class="rel-prod-title">Western Digital 1TB</p>
    <p class="rel-prod-price" id="price_format_2">139.95</p>
    <a href="#" title="Western Digital 1TB" class="gray-btn-sm add-to-cart text-shadow">add to cart</a>
</div>

<div class="rel-prod-item">
    <img src="assets/product-photos/title-of-the-related-product_thumbnail.jpg" alt="Western Digital 1TB" />
    <p class="rel-prod-title">Western Digital 1TB</p>
    <p class="rel-prod-price" id="price_format_3">49.95</p>
    <a href="#" title="Western Digital 1TB" class="gray-btn-sm add-to-cart text-shadow">add to cart</a>
</div>
```

The designer made all the prices have the digits after the . be superscript. So your choice is to either have the cms spit out the price in 2 parts from the backend and put it back together with `<sup>` tags around it, or just leave it alone and change it via the DOM. That's what I opted for and here's what I came up with:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var pricelist = document.getElementsByClassName("rel-prod-price");
    var price_id = "";
    for (var b = 1; b <= pricelist.length; b++) {
        var price_id = "price_format_" + b;
        var price_original = document.getElementById(price_id).innerHTML;
        var price_parts = price_original.split(".");
        var formatted_price = price_parts[0] + ".<b>" + price_parts[1] + "</b>";
        document.getElementById(price_id).innerHTML = formatted_price;
    }

}
```

And here's the CSS I used:

```
.rel-prod-item p.rel-prod-price b {
    font-size: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: -4px;
}
```

I hope this helps someone keep all their hair :-)

[Here's a screenshot of the finished product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lmgMo.png)

Comment: Yes. As you can see, the variable `price_id` is, well, a variable... that gets passed into `document.getElementById` in javascript...

Comment: OK, although I do not think it's related, the question was asked in 2011 and also have an accepted answer in 2011 and has nothing to do with `css` `cms` and `backend` code, You could just post that part of your code which was related to the question!

Comment: For asking question, it's better to post as much information as you can in which will help others to have a better understanding of your problem. But for posting an answer, it's better to post the code which is specifically written for that question. But keep up good work :)